# sed substitute dash with underscore until character is reached

Tags: sed

Here is a sample text

```
enable-threads       = yes
enable-shared        = yes
enable-parser        = yes
DAL-II-VERSION     = 7.1.0
DAL-II-MAJOR       = -L -f -g
DAL-II-MINOR         = 1
```

I want to substitute all dashs (-) with underscores in everyline until = sign is reached.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `sed` doesn't support look-behinds or look-aheads. But `perl` and `ssed` do (see Rob's answer). If `perl` is unavailable, here's one way using `awk`:

```
awk -F= 'OFS=FS { gsub("-", "_", $1); }1' file.txt
```

Output:

```
enable_threads       = yes
enable_shared        = yes
enable_parser        = yes
DAL_II_VERSION     = 7.1.0
DAL_II_MAJOR       = -L -f -g
DAL_II_MINOR         = 1
```

HTH

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to do something like that is using a [look-ahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). `sed` doesn't support them, but `perl` does:

```
perl -pe 's/-(?=.*=)/_/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'h;s/=.*//;y/-/_/;G;s/\n[^=]*//' file
```